# Skateboard, roller blades or?

Tags: time, travel

I am trying to optimize my daily commute. I usually walk slightly over a kilometer (slightly under a mile) (asphalt sidewalk) to the station I depart from and about the same distance from the station I arrive at to my destination.

There are buses, but those are a bad option due to heavy traffic. I can rent a city bicycle for my "home - station" segment, but not for the other segment. So I settled on bying a... "personal transportation device"? (is there a word for it?)

There are lots of them on the market: skateboards, bikes, electric skateboards and electric bikes, roller blades, [Skyrunners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugCMXct4nrs), waveboards and longboards, scooters... I need to pick one that is

- Fast (my goal is cutting travel time, after all)
- Small, so that I can take it with me on a train. Moscow Metro doesn't allow bicycles, because [this](http://img0.joyreactor.cc/pics/post/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE-1889217.jpeg).

What would be my best bet?

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks SE. I'm afraid that this question does not seem to need a life hack, as defined in the [help], because it is mostly just asking for a recommendation on a mode of transportation, not an outside the box solution to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Skyrunners are fine if you're actually going to run all the way, but you'd probably need a shower afterwards. A bike would be good, but again, you'd probably need a shower AND somewhere to chain the bike up for the day.

I'd go for rollerblades or rollerboots - you can take those off and keep in a bag for the journey (the same bag you'll have our shoes in on the way to the station if you get the ones you don't wear shoes with). You'd get there faster without running at all. Electric scooter is the second option, not sure which of those would take up less room in a crowd, but I don't think a scooter would fit in a bag...